# How to use TCPDF on LARAVEL 4

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, tcpdf

Good Day,

Can anyone help me how to use TCPDF in Laravel 4, I mean from installing on via composer update to generating a pdf from the view  or through the controller. Ive tried to search on Google but I cant find a comprehensive tutorial on how to use it on Laravel 4. Sorry for this noobish question :) .

Thanks for the help. I will really appreciate it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definitive version of TCPDF can be added to your Laravel application by adding the tecnick.com/tcpdf package to your composer.json file as follows:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.*", // This is the line to add
```

Running `composer update` will add the library to your project.

You can then instantiate instances of `TCPDF` and work with it as per the documentation.

Here's an example of a method that you could add to a controller that would construct a very simple PDF file and send it to the browser for download:

```
public function getPdftest()
{
    $pdf = new TCPDF();

    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Text(90, 140, 'This is a test');
    $filename = storage_path() . '/test.pdf';
    $pdf->output($filename, 'F');

    return Response::download($filename);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @JamesG but can u teach me how instantiate instance too.. i mean how to add alias on it :) thank you very much!

Comment: The second line of code in the sample shows an instance of the `TCPDF` class (`$pdf`) being instantiated. I have added a complete copy of the controller code here: http://pastebin.com/Q41S6g7Z If I get time I may write a tutorial for this, as there seem to be a few people requesting it. In the mean time, if this information has helped you at all, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thank You very much @JamesG !! it worked! I did have a problem on my php_fileinfo extension but I just fixed by enabling it through php.ini on my Xampp! other else works fine! thank you for your tutorial! really appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

To install TCPDF, add this in your composer.json file require block,

```
"laurentbrieu/tcpdf": "dev-master"
```

Now it looks like,

```
....

"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "laurentbrieu/tcpdf": "dev-master"
    },
......
```

Then update using composer, run the following in your project root.

```
composer update
```

Now you can call TCPDF functions in your laravel project by adding alias.

See this for more details - https://packagist.org/packages/laurentbrieu/tcpdf

Comment: thank you for that answer @iDevoc !! can u teach me how to add alias too.. I mean its path.. I tried 'TCPDF'=>'vendor\tecnick.com\tcpdf' but no luck.. does it have also a provider?? sorry again its just that theres no proper documentation for laravel4 provided on its site.. thanks for the effort!